# Having two projects in solution each with there own AutoMapper Configuration

Tags: c#, automapper

I would like to have two projects in my solution that have the own, auto mapper conjugation.

I have a ASP.Net MVC project, and bellow that there is a class library that use entity framework.

The class library uses EF to get entities then uses auto mapper to turn them into DTOs, The MVC app uses auto mapper to turn the DTOs to MVC models.

I just don’t know correct way to set up auto mapper for this, In the MVC project, Global.asax.cs  Application_Start() I have AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();  which calls.

```
 public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(c =>
        {
            c.CreateMap<FooDTO, Foo>().ReverseMap();
        });
    }
```

Which is straight forward as that will get called when the application starts.
The bit that I can work out is the class library.

In the class library I created a second auto mapper set up

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(c =>
        {
            c.CreateMap<Foo, FooDTO>().ReverseMap();
        });
    }
}
```

In the class library I created a FooService class and in the constructor, I have

```
public FooService()
    {
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
    }
```

So not only does this smell bad, as I would need to have AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure(); in every service constructor. But it also give the following error when the code gets to AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

**Mapper already initialized. You must call Initialize once per application domain/process.**

So what is the best way to set up auto mapper for this?

Comment: Could you use [profiles](http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html#profile-instances) for this?

Comment: Looking at your use case here, why not just use Automapper once?

Comment: As @stuartd says, profiles are the way to go here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically set up Automapper in the root of the application (in your case, the ASP.NET MVC project). From there, it typically has access to any/all types that require mapping, since it will have a project reference to your EF class library. You should be able to map from EF entities to DTOs and from DTOs to MVC models both from this project.

As an aside, I question why you're using DTOs in this scenario. It's definitely a good design to avoid using your EF entities directly from your MVC controllers (don't expose them to model binding), but typically you can map to/from your domain entities/data model inside the controllers. For example, let's say you have a Customer entity that EF is responsible for storing. In your CustomersController, you might have a CustomerViewModel that you pass to a View or a CustomerDTO that you return from an API call. You might accept a NewCustomerModel from a POST. In any of these cases, you would likely map between your MVC-specific models and your domain entities within the controller (or in a filter or in a service the controller calls). But you wouldn't need a 3rd set of types involved in the mapping.